# Scatter Plot Interval Lenth

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot in my application and I need to have an intervallength of dates on the x-axis. My Problem is that the date intervals need to be half a year. How can I accomplish this considering leap-years etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom axis labels. Compute the locations based on a starting date and 6-month intervals. See Apple's [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html) for help with the date math.